# How to customize pagination in wice_grid gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wice-grid

I have a pagination like:

« First ‹ Prev 1 2 ... 13 14 15 16 **17** 18 19 20 21 ... 24 25 Next › Last »

This is too long. How can I make this shorter, e.g.:

« ‹ 15 16 **17** 18 19 › »

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: How do you generate the pagination links? Do you use a gem?

Comment: I use wice grid https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid gem and wice grid uses kaminari gem.

Answer (score 0):

wice_grid uses Kaminari internally so you should just be able to configure it in an initializer:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  window               2 # 4 by default
end
```

and then you would need to override these I18n values in your locale:

```
en:
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "&laquo; First"
      last: "Last &raquo;"
      previous: "&lsaquo; Prev"
      next: "Next &rsaquo;"
      truncate: "&hellip;"
```

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Comment: I tried to
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.window = 2
end
but the result is the same.

Comment: Ah...  I just found this --> https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid/blob/8db9abc6ab26a2e906b34939469ed04fa4fd17c5/lib/wice/helpers/wice_grid_view_helpers.rb#L625

Comment: looks like your only choice is to overwrite that method or define your own paginate method that will override those parameters and call down to Kaminari directly.